# data in $_POST across multiple pages

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I wrote scripts for simple login. When successfully login and click the link "back to login", I was not able to have the previous login username filled. I know using $_COOKIE['username'] for the value of username works, but I am wondering why $_POST['username'] does not work? Thank you!

login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<form action="./loginProcess.php" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) : ''; ?>"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

loginProcess.php

```
<?php
echo "welcome,  ".$_POST['username'].", login success!!";
echo "<br/><a href='login.php'>Back to login</a><br>";
if(!empty($_COOKIE['lastVist'])){
    echo "your last login time：".$_COOKIE['lastVist'];
    setcookie("lastVist",date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),time()+24*3600*30);
}else{
    echo "you first login time：";
}
setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time()+24*3600*30);
?>
```

Comment: You could use $_REQUEST['username'] in your login.php. The actual reason why POST won't work after you hit the "back" button, is that you perform a GET request.

Comment: You can use $_SESSION please read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: @ chickenchilli When performing the GET request, is everything in the $_POST cleared up?

Answer (score 0):

A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages.

Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer and unlike post as it has information for specific request sent by user.

When we use an application, we open it and do some changes, then we close it. This is much like a Session, so to preserve information we have per session global array in php `$_SESSION`.

A session is started with the `session_start()` function and values are stored in simply associative array fashion `$_SESSION['key'] = $value;`.

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<form action="./loginProcess.php" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['username']) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']) : ''; ?>"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**loginProcess.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "welcome,  ".$_POST['username'].", login success!!";
echo "<br/><a href='login.php'>Back to login</a><br>";
if(isset($_SESSION['lastVisit'])){
    echo "your last login time：".$_SESSION['lastVisit'];
}else{
    echo "you first login time：".$_SESSION['lastVisit'];
    $_SESSION['lastVisit'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
}

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle, in *loginProcess.php*, if you would have used, for example, a form with a *hidden* input containing the username value, then this value would have been readable in the *login.php* - after clicking the *"back to login"* anchor:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>, login success!!
<br>
<form id="backToLoginForm" action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>" />
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.forms['backToLoginForm'].submit();">
        Back to login
    </a>
</form>
```

But you really shouldn't do what you want to do. E.g. to go back to the *login.php* without logging-out first - at least. If you would do it and complete other credentials - in the *login.php* - as the ones used for the first login, then you would still need to logout the previous user before validating the new credentials. This would be a bad management of active session, cookies, etc.

More of it, the autocomplete of login credentials is a job for the *password managers*, or of the *form fillers*, not of your own code - unless it's part of the validation process of the currently given login credentials (see the code example below).

So, as an alternative to your approach, my suggestion would be the following *login.php* code. No need for a *loginProcess.php* page anymore:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Operations upon form submission.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Validate the username.
    if (!isset($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide the username.';
    }/* Here other password validations using elseif statement. */

    // Validate the password.
    if (!isset($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide the password.';
    } /* Here other password validations using elseif statement. */

    // Get the posted data.
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!isset($errors)) {
        /*
         * Check the given credentials in the db. If the user doesn't exist, add an error:
         */
        // $errors[] = 'Wrong credentials. Please try again.';

        /*
         * ... else add only the user id - fetched from db - to session.
         * Don't add other user related details to session. If, in other pages, 
         * you want to use other user details, fetch them there using the user id.
         */
        if (!isset($errors)) {
            $_SESSION['userId'] = 43;

            // Redirect to the welcome page.
            header('Location: welcome.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Login</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .form-control {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            label {
                display: inline-block;
                min-width: 80px;
            }

            .messages {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .error {
                color: #c00;
            }

            button {
                padding: 5px 10px;
                background-color: #8daf15;
                color: #fff;
                border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="messages">
            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="error">
                        <?php echo $error; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($username) ? $username : ''; ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo isset($password) ? $password : ''; ?>">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
                Login
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```